# excel vba domdocument parsing xml from TNT tracking system: in some pcs object load return no document

Tags: excel, xml, vba, parsing, domdocument

I have a function to parse an xml document received from the tracking system of TNT courier,
this is example of a query url i'm using:
https://www.tnt.it/tracking/getXMLTrack?WT=1&ConsigNos=RL38536236

the function worked correctly on all PCs until yesterday,
when on some PCs the method .Load(URL) of DOMDocument object returns false result and the DocumentElement property is null,

the thing is: if i browse to that url (i used firefox, chrome, edge, iexplore)
the xml is showed correctly!

this is the code:

```
Function TrackTNTlist(LDV As String) As Collection

Dim TNTlist As New Collection

Dim Obj As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim Verifica As Boolean
Dim XMLTNT As String

Dim NodoLista As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim NodoSingolo As IXMLDOMNode
Dim Nome As IXMLDOMNode
Dim DataConsegna As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NomeRicevente As IXMLDOMNode
Dim Destinatario As IXMLDOMNode
Dim ConsignmentDetails As IXMLDOMNode
Dim DataPrevConsegna As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NuovaLDV As IXMLDOMNode
Dim Dest As String, DatiSped As String

On Error GoTo RigaErrore

XMLTNT = "https://www.tnt.it/tracking/getXMLTrack?WT=1&ConsigNos=" & LDV

Set Obj = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Obj.async = False
Verifica = Obj.Load(XMLTNT)

If Verifica = True Then
    MsgBox "File XML " & XMLTNT & "loaded"
Else
    MsgBox "File XML NOT loaded"
    TNTlist.Add "ERROR - XML tracking data not loaded"
    Exit Function
End If

Set NodoSingolo = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/StatusDetails/StatusDescription")

If NodoSingolo Is Nothing Then

    TNTlist.Add "LDV non trovata"

Else
    Set NodoList = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Consignment/StatusDetails")
    Set ConsignmentDetails = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/ConsignmentDetails")

    DatiSped = ""
    DatiSped = "LETTERA DI VETTURA: " & LDV & Chr(10)
    
    If Not ConsignmentDetails Is Nothing Then
        DatiSped = DatiSped & "RIF. MITTENTE: " & ConsignmentDetails.ChildNodes(0).Text & Chr(10)
        DatiSped = DatiSped & "TIPO SERVIZIO: " & ConsignmentDetails.ChildNodes(1).Text & Chr(10)
        DatiSped = DatiSped & "NUM. COLLI: " & ConsignmentDetails.ChildNodes(3).Text & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    
    Set NodoSingolo = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/StatusDetails/StatusDescription")
    
    Dest = ""
    Set DataConsegna = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/DeliveryDate")
    Set NomeRicevente = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/CollectionName")
    Set Destinatario = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/ReceiverDetails")
    Set DataPrevConsegna = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/DueDate")
    Set NuovaLDV = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/HeldInDepotDetails/HID1ReplacingDoc")
    
    If NodoSingolo.Text = "Spedizione consegnata" Then
        Dest = "CONSEGNATA A: " & Chr(13)
    Else
        Dest = "PREVISTA CONSEGNA A: " & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    If Not Destinatario Is Nothing Then
        Dest = Dest & Destinatario.ChildNodes(4).Text
        Dest = Dest & " (" & Destinatario.ChildNodes(6).Text & ")" & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    If Not DataPrevConsegna Is Nothing Then
        Dest = Dest & DataPrevConsegna.ChildNodes(0).Text & Chr(10)
    End If

    
    If Not DataConsegna Is Nothing Then
        Dest = Dest & "Data consegna: " & DataConsegna.Text & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    If Not NomeRicevente Is Nothing Then
        Dest = Dest & "Ha ritirato: " & NomeRicevente.Text & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    If Not NuovaLDV Is Nothing Then
        Dest = Dest & "NUOVA LETTERA DI VETTURA: " & NuovaLDV.Text & Chr(10)
    End If
    
    Dest = Dest & "Dettaglio tracking:" & Chr(10)
    
    TNTlist.Add DatiSped & Chr(10) & Dest & Chr(10)
    
    For Each Nome In NodoList
        
        TNTlist.Add Nome.ChildNodes(1).Text
        TNTlist.Add Nome.ChildNodes(2).Text
    
    Next
    
End If

salto = 1
If salto <> 1 Then
    Set NodoSingolo = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/StatusDetails/StatusDescription")
    
    
    If NodoSingolo Is Nothing Then
        TNTlist.Add "LDV non trovata"
    Else
        If NodoSingolo.Text = "Spedizione consegnata" Then

            Set DataConsegna = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/DeliveryDate")
            Set NomeRicevente = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/CollectionName")
            Set Destinatario = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Consignment/ReceiverDetails")
            Dest = Destinatario.ChildNodes(4).Text
            Dest = Dest & " (" & Destinatario.ChildNodes(5).Text & ")"
            
            TNTlist.Add NodoSingolo.Text & " : " & Dest & " - " & NomeRicevente.Text & " - " & DataConsegna.Text
            TNTlist.Add DataConsegna.Text
        
        End If
    
    End If
End If

Set TrackTNTlist = TNTlist

Exit Function

RigaErrore:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
Application.EnableEvents = True
Resume Next

End Function
```

the problem occurs only in few pcs,
they have the same system configuration,
below two screen shots, one from a pc where the function work correctly ad one from another where the problem occurs.

[debug screenshot of correct execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m6EQ.png)

[debug screenshot of error execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOwyl.png)

in both pcs browsing to the url show the xml correctly.

Could anyone help me to understand what might cause the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Francesco

Comment: In my experience, this error is always related with something in the Xml which is not wrong. Do you have a LDV which generates an error on some PCs?

Comment: Please have a look at `DOMDocument.parseError`. Simplest usage in your code: `MsgBox "File XML NOT loaded. Reason: " & Obj.parseError.reason`. What reason is shown?

Comment: The reason is "Download della risorsa specificata non riuscito" (it's in italian) translation in english should be: "download of the specified resource has failed".

Comment: That sounds pretty clear: `https://www.tnt.it/tracking/getXMLTrack` does not respond for that combination of parameters. Either the parameters are wrong or there is a temporary server problem or a temporary internet connection problem of the client.